# Switch to turn off Asp.Net website compilation in cruise control build

Tags: asp.net, web, cruisecontrol.net

Is there a switch to pass to the devenv task in Cruise Control to turn off / on website compilation.

I want certain builds to build the site (very time consuming with batch='false') + run Simian etc, while more frequent builds only build the libraries

AFAIK this is generally controlled by the 'Build Website as part of Solution' option, is there a way to change this through CC.NEt config?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can fine-tune which projects get built with [Soluion Configurations](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/aaronhallberg/archive/2007/06/25/solution-configurations.aspx):

[image]

and then tell CriuseControl which solution configuration to build.

Comment: Yes - that should be perfect. Thanks